# Amazon S3 Bulk delete empty folders

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

How can we delete empty folders from amazon s3 ?
I am dealing with large numger of files and folders. So manual deletion is inappropriate. Is there any lifecycle policy can be used ?

Answer (score 0):

The below command should do it,

> s3cmd ls --recursive s3://BUCKET_NAME | ruby -rdate -ne 'date, time,
>   size, uri = $_.split; puts uri if size == "0"' | xargs s3cmd del

s3cmd can be installed from,

https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd

Hope it helps.